# Having trouble with the definition of functors in terms of nerves

Tags: category-theory, functors

In a brief note nlab mentions functors can be thought of maps between nerves. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functor#definition I don't really get this definition.

I'm interested because I'm playing around with some foundational math and thought it might be easier to manipulate functors defined in terms of nerves instead of the usual way around. I also feel like the definition might work better with higher category theory.

In my little [Coq library](https://gitlab.com/sstewartgallus/category-fun/-/blob/master/src/Infinity.v#L165) , ignoring some extraneous details, I define a functor the usual way basically something like:

```
Record functor (C D: Category) := {
  fobj: object C -> object D ;
  map: forall A B, hom A B -> hom (fobj A) (fobj B)
}.
```

And also satisfying the usual conditions.

My intuition is the definition in terms of nerves is that instead of record fields one would number off types of n-cells.

```
Definition functor A B := forall (n: ncell), cell n A -> cell n B.
```

Only having 0 and one cells. But I'm having trouble with the exact types.

Comment: Nerves, being simplicial sets, are much more complicated objects than categories. You should note that the people working on homotopy type theory haven't yet figured out how to work with simplicial objects internally.

Comment: @Zhen Lin Wouldn't you only need the full definition of nerves when using infinity categories? Within some finite (n, r) category you could unfold things a bit right?

Comment: If you are only working with 1-categories, then yes, you can truncate above degree 2 and still get a fully faithful embedding. I am not convinced this is easier than working with categories as traditionally formulated.